# What causes "'RefreshIndicator' isn't a function" error?

Tags: flutter, dart, refresh, pull-to-refresh

```dart
if (subStatuses.isEmpty) {
  // No second tab bar needed if subStatuses is empty
  return RefreshIndicator(
    child: ListView.builder(
      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: applicants.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final applicant = applicants[index];
        return listViewItem_new(
          context,
          applicant,
          true,
          statuses,
          profilemodel.id != null
              ? profilemodel.id!.toInt()
              : 467,
          index,
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

I'm trying to use `RefreshIndicator`, but I'm getting this error:

> 'RefreshIndicator' isn't a function.
> Try correcting the name to match an existing function, or define a method or function named 'RefreshIndicator'.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you show the imports in the file you're working on?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the on Refresh Method

```
return RefreshIndicator(
  onRefresh: () {
    //write the call to method you want to run on refreshing
  },
  child: ListView.builder(
    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: applicants.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      final applicant = applicants[index];
      return listViewItem_new(
        context,
        applicant,
        true,
        statuses,
        profilemodel.id != null ? profilemodel.id!.toInt() : 467,
        index,
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: i tried but not working

Comment: try importing this way: import 'package:flutter/material.dart' as material;  and change RefreshIndicator to material.RefreshIndicator

Comment: please remove space after "package: " in your material import, hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is that you imported `package:flutter/material.dart` and  `package:pull_to_refresh/pull_to_refresh.dart`, which both export a `RefreshIndicator` class. If you're going to use [`RefreshIndicator`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RefreshIndicator-class.html) from the Flutter framework, you need to hide [`RefreshIndicator`](https://pub.dev/documentation/pull_to_refresh/latest/pulltorefresh/RefreshIndicator-class.html) from the `pull_to_refresh` import like this:

```dart
import 'package:pull_to_refresh/pull_to_refresh.dart' hide RefreshIndicator;
```

Or if you're not using that package, just remove the import.